# How to display String [] options in java

Tags: java

```
String[] options = { "3 km/hr", "5 km/hr", "8 km/hr", "9 km/hr" };
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want something like this: `for(String str: options){System.out.println(str);}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either iterate over the array and "display" each element yourself or use `Arrays.toString(options)` that will create nicely formatted string representation.

Comment: i want to display string inside option as an answer to a question, for the end use to see

Comment: full question: if (aptitudeAttempt==0){
                       // Display question
                   System.out.println("\nQuestion ");
                   System.out.println("In one hour, a boat goes 11 km/hr along the stream and 5 km/hr against the stream. The speed of the boat in still water (in km/hr) is:");
                   String[] options = { "3 km/hr", "5 km/hr", "8 km/hr", "9 km/hr" };
                   String answer = "C"; 
                   
                  
                   displayOption(options);
                    
                   // Get user's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to print the values, you could try:

```
    String[] options = { "3 km/hr", "5 km/hr", "8 km/hr", "9 km/hr" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(options));
    --> the output would be: [3 km/hr, 5 km/hr, 8 km/hr, 9 km/hr]
```

Or you could do it by hand, with:

```
    for (String option : options) {
        System.out.println(option);
    }
    --> the output would be:
    3 km/hr
    5 km/hr
    ...etc
```